# How to load newer version of json4s in Spark 2.1 executor?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The app I'm working on has to run under Spark 2.1 on Azure. I updated `build.sbt` for the app with a slightly newer version of json4s (from 3.2.11 to 3.3.0)
to get bug fix for Double serialization:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.3.0",
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % "3.3.0",
```

However, when using json4s's FieldSerializer under Spark 2.1:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats +
    new FieldSerializer[MyClass](renameTo("name", "anotherName"))
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.FieldSerializer$.$lessinit$greater$default$3()Z
```

Note this change in FieldSerializer's declaration from 3.2.11

```
case class FieldSerializer[A](
  serializer:   PartialFunction[(String, Any), Option[(String, Any)]] = Map(),
  deserializer: PartialFunction[JField, JField] = Map()
)(implicit val mf: Manifest[A])
```

to 3.3.0:

```
case class FieldSerializer[A](
  serializer:   PartialFunction[(String, Any), Option[(String, Any)]] = Map(),
  deserializer: PartialFunction[JField, JField] = Map(),
  includeLazyVal: Boolean = false
)(implicit val mf: Manifest[A])
```

My interpretation of the error message is that the third parameter is not declared, which would indicate that somehow json4s 3.2.11 is still being used.
Given that, I declared the json4s libraries as 'provided', and named them in the start script:

```
spark-submit
...
--packages org.json4s:json4s-native_2.11:3.3.0,org.json4s:json4s-ext_2.11:3.3.0
...
```

This does cause the jars to be downloaded to ~/.ivy2/jars, but the same error occurs. Is there a way to dump the libraries Spark is using for the executors? I used `--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-verbose"`, but that never showed
the FieldSerializer being loaded, even though it showed a long list of class loads.

Is there a way to force Spark to use version 3.3.0 in the executors, or to not load 3.2.11?

EDIT:

I don't have a general solution for printing library versions, but for json4s I can print `BuildInfo.version` at runtime, which shows that
version 3.2.11 is being used with or without `--packages`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is quite easy, actually:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.json4s.**" -> "shaded_json4s.@1").inAll
),
```

I'd rather use inLibrary/inProject, so I'll do that here shortly.

In the process of finding the answer, I also stumbled across a duplicate question.